# Different widgets in sidebar on sub-children pages?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, pages

I'm working on project, where I have different widgets on pages and also different order.
Example - on About page I may have **chat widget**, then **e-mail sign-up widget**, then **testimonials widget**. On other page I may have **testimonials widget** only, followed by **chat widget**. I'm using this code to show widgets on pages and children pages

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ){  ?>       

<?php }elseif ( is_page('areas-we-service') || $post->post_parent == '16' ){ ?>
Do stuff here   
<?php }elseif ( is_page('products') || $post->post_parent == '14' ){ ?>
Do stuff here
 <?php }else{ ?> <?php } ?>
```

and  it work. The problem is that it not work on subchildrent pages e.g. Product -> Product 1 -> Product 1.1
On Product 1.1 I don't have widgets.
So, my question is, how to change code above to show widgets on subchildren, sub-subchildren etc. pages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I use [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) at my blog. It is not most convenient solution around, but definitely one of the most flexible. Widgets can be displayed/hidden based on arbitrary PHP condition. Works great with [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and when that is not enough you just write your own conditions and use them.

Answer (score 0):

look at [Custom sidebars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-sidebars/) plugin that lets you define sidebars per page/post basis.

or you can use is_page() with  the page id like this:

```
is_page('322')
```

that way you define per page.

hope this helps.